# I want the button to be removed first and then execute the content in function cam()

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

Code:

```
p.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        System.out.println("Welcome to Guess the number Game");
        System.out.println("You have 3 chances to guess a number between 0 and 10 excluding 10");

        ne.remove(p);

        // ne.removeAll();
        ne.revalidate();
        ne.repaint();
    }

    public void cam() {

        gamer2 game = new gamer2();
        game.generatenum();
    }
});
```

`p` is a JButton.

- Reason why I have not called `cam()` inside `actionPerformed()` is that if I do that the button will only be removed after `generatenum()` is executed.I want the button to be removed first.

Comment: What is that `cam` function doing in the middle there?

Comment: On clicking the button,the button is supposed to call a function from another class.That's the reason I have used it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The method from the type is never used locally warning for non-private methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631664/the-method-from-the-type-is-never-used-locally-warning-for-non-private-methods)

Comment: Your code does not call the cam() method at all.   This triggers a compilation warning.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen any idea on how to call it?

Comment: Why is it in there at all?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I want the function `generatenum()` to be called when the button is clicked.But if I add it inside `actionPerformed()` function,the button will only be removed after the complete program is executed.

Comment: Using `System.out.println()` inside a Swing ActionListener indicates you are unfamiliar with Swing programming.  You may want to reread the Oracle Java Tutorial section on Swing?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I am only using Swing for a button.The rest is done using Eclipse Console. That's the reason I am using `System.out.println()`. I know that it wouldn't print on the JFrame.

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cam() methods belongs to the anonymous class (ActionListener's subclass),  in this anonymous class no method calls cam().that's why u receive that warning

in my opinion, u should do this

```
p.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        System.out.println("Welcome to Guess the number Game");
        System.out.println("You have 3 chances to guess a number between 0 and 10 excluding 10");

        ne.remove(p);

        // ne.removeAll();
        ne.revalidate();
        ne.repaint();
        cam();
    }

});

public void cam() {

    gamer2 game = new gamer2();
    game.generatenum();
}
```

or u can do this

```
p.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        System.out.println("Welcome to Guess the number Game");
        System.out.println("You have 3 chances to guess a number between 0 and 10 excluding 10");

        ne.remove(p);

        // ne.removeAll();
        ne.revalidate();
        ne.repaint();
        cam();
    }

    public void cam() {

        gamer2 game = new gamer2();
        game.generatenum();
    }
});
```

Comment: I want the content `cam()` to be executed only after the button is removed.Your solution would block the EDT.

Comment: use Container.addContainerListener to be invoked when p is removed from a container